# Onclick function produces "Function statement require a function name" ERROR

Tags: reactjs, onclick, arrow-functions

I have a React component which renders a gantt chart inside which I am rendering an image which is supposed to fire an action on click. Due to the way the chart library is set up, I have to pass the image tag as regular HTML tag as so :

[image]

This implantation with the arrow function produces an error:

[image]

When I tested if the function iconClick is seen by the component with:

```
onClick='${this.iconClick()}'
```

the function worked correctly but of course it fired on page load instead of on click. Am I missing something with my arrow function set up?

Comment: do post the whole code?

Answer (score 0):

`JSX` is not `HTML`.
You are trying to manipulate DOM directly using string interpolation. In normal HTML code you would provide `onclick` attribute which is JS string to be evaluated when the element is clicked.

In `JSX` you provide `onClick` function that to be called later.

When using react, you are not supposed to mutate DOM like you do here.